# What is the meaning of the invariant $S^{ij} S_{ij}$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I came across $S^{ij}$ when studying GR and Riemann Curvature.

$$S^{ij} = \oint_{\text{loop on the surface}}  x^i dx^j - x^j dx^i \approx \text{Area Enclosed By The Loop.}$$

What is $S^{ij} S_{ij} ?$

And does this mean something like "area" in any coordinates or does this have to be done in cartesian coordinates to give "area".

I used this to parameterize a circle and find the area.

Then I calculated it in polar coordinates by doing the integral such that $x=r$ and $y=\theta$ and by transforming the tensor and got the same answer, $2\pi r$. And that's not an area.

Comment: *And how can "area" be a tensor rather than a scalar?* Are you familiar with area as a *vector*, such as $d\mathbf A$ when computing flux through a surface?

Comment: “Area enclosed” by *what*?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes. But I always thought of that as a useful convention. Such as for when you're calculating flux. Enclosed by the loop of the integral.

Comment: What area does a non-planar loop enclose? And what is a plane in GR?

Comment: Based on your edit (“loop on the surface”), are you talking about 2D manifolds?

Comment: the loop on a 2 d surface. it the indices run over more than 2 numbers than maybe it's a volume. I don't know.  I suppose it could be a volume in spacetime.

Comment: It doesn’t have the dimensions to be a volume.

Comment: @G.Smith I've seen a very abstract version of it where it seems like the indices could be greater than 2. But the most concrete thing calculation is where $x=rcos{\theta}$ $y=rsin{\theta}$ and the integral is done over theta to get the area of a circle $ 2\pi r^2 $.

Comment: Related question for Euclidean space: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693438/how-do-i-find-the-area-of-a-general-closed-curve-and-then-generalisation-to-mu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here, and say that this must have come up in the discussion of parallel transport.

1. Yes, it a tensor. This is fairly simple to prove. Since this is a contour integral, we can perform the following parameterization:
   $$ x^{\rho} \rightarrow x^{\rho}(\tau)$$
   Where $\tau$ has the usual meaning of proper time measured along the path.
   You can therefore then, do the following:
   $$S^{ij} = \oint x^{i} dx^{j} = \oint x^{i} \frac{dx^{j}}{d\tau} d\tau$$
   $\tau$ is a scalar, and the kernel consists of products of two tensors. Therefore, $S^{ij}$ is indeed a tensor.
2. As far as I know, $S^{ij}S_{ij}$ does not have any importance in physics at least.
   I recommend Weinberg's Gravitation and Cosmology - Chapter: Curvature for parallel transport.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $S_{ij}$ (BTW I feel like it is more natural to have contravariant indexes for this) as an area of an "infinitesimally small parallelogram". To define that parallelogram, you need two vectors showing you which way the sides point and how long they are. So, S is an object that takes in two vectors and gives you an area enclosed by them, therefore it needs two indices.

As to what the geometric meaning of $S^{ij}S_{ij}$ is, I will have to think a bit about that. It is a number that is independent of the coordinate choice, so it must have some geometric meaning. If we think of a simple example of a 3D Euclidean space with Cartesian coordinates we should be able to figure out what it is.